# Making a Fill In Questionaire Java Excercise

Tags: java

Before I begin I want to point out that I'm in severe stress and frustration due to not being able to make this excercise. I have searched and asked all over the internet and I feel hopeless. As my last hope I came to Stack Overflow to ask this question. I do not understand the excercise. It is a very strange one. I would be forever grateful to you if you could assist me in making this excercise that I am stuck with for a month. My life really depends on this. Please help me.

```
public class Question {
    private String text;
    private String answer;

    public Question() {
        text = "";
        answer = "";
    }

    public void setText(String questionText) {
        text = questionText;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String correctResponse){
        answer = correctResponse;
    }

    public boolean checkAnswer(String response){
        return response.equals(answer);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(text); 
    }
    }
```

Im going to add a class FillInQuestion to this class. Such a question is constructed with a string that contains the answer, surrounded by _ _, for exam ple, The inventor of Java was *James Gosling*. The question should be displayed as The inventor of Java was _____. But I'm not sure how I could make this? Could I receive the way to make a string that contains the answer in such a way.

The question is cited as "Add a class FillInQuestion to the question hierarchy of Section 9.1. Such a question is
constructed with a string that contains the answer, surrounded by `_ _`, for example,
"`The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_`". The question should be displayed as
`The inventor of Java was _____`"

How can I construct a string that contains the answer like that?
How can I display `_James Gosling_` like `____`? 
What do they mean. I dont understand.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot ask your teacher to explain what he want?

Comment: I'm self taught. I bought a book and Im learning it myself. I need to understand every excercise that's a principle for good learning.

Comment: I think the input is like `The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_`. To extract the answer you may work with [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) or regular expressions.

Comment: But what kind of input is this? What's this for fill in questionaire? I just dont get it

Comment: I have seen this exercice a month ago I believe, the idea was simply to store those questions with answer surrounded by `_` and when you want to output the question, replace the answer `_the answer_` by `________`, (no specific length). And of course, you need to extract that answer to be able to check the answer inputed by the user I guess. But there is not much more to say, if you don't get it with this, well you should take a break ;)

Comment: Explaining like this just doesn't make it visible for me man. Could you please give me a java example of this to make me understand? I mean it I really dont get it until I see it in java.

Comment: 1. Store question with _James Gosling. 2. Make the program convert _James Gosling_ into _____  3. Make the program check the answer. Is this it? This is the fill in questionaire? Thats all?

Comment: You mean until I give you the solution ? ;) You should train yourself to understand verbose problem since the user that will explain the requirements will be even less precise than this.

Comment: Must the user be able to type on the ____ in the output of IDE? Because I dont think thats working

Comment: @michaelgreen In my answer you "just" need to implement the two methods. The input string is something like `The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_`

Comment: @michaelgreen so your question is about the GUI of this problem. Don't bother with that, in a console, you simply print the question then below ask the answer. The design is not part of the problem

Comment: Okay thank you. But all I need now is a method that can convert the _ James Gosling _ in a question to _____. How can I do this?

Comment: You can try with java string functions, java string functions provides features to find and replace the Strings.

Comment: **Hey but this was your question a month ago** ... [don't duplicate the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786040/how-can-i-construct-a-string-which-has-an-answer-for-a-fill-in-quiz-surrounded-b) please ...

Comment: Im very sorry I was frustrated and I needed help

Comment: How can I add code in a comment?

Comment: @michaelgreen, you can edit the question, code in comment is not readable if it's more than one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String question = "The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(.*?)_");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(question);
        if (m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("question before edit : " + question);
            String answer = m.group(1);
            System.out.println("Answer after edit : " + m.group(1));
            question = question.replace(answer, "_______");

            System.out.println("question after edit : " + question);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hello ! Whats the .*? for and the m.group(1) mean?

Comment: Hello I want to thank everyone greatly for helping me out! I have added this code and I have been able to finish this excercise, Alex, Anurag, Stefan thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the input will be a `String` and you need to extract the answer and create the question text.

```
public FillInQuestion(String fillInQuestion) {
    // The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_ -> James Gosling
    this.answer = extractAnswer(fillInQuestion);
    // The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_ -> The inventor of Java was _____
    this.text = createQuestion(fillInQuestion);
}
```